# How to do machine translation with no labeled data?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, machine-translation, unlabeled-datasets

Is it be possible to train a neural network, with no parallel bilingual data, for machine translation?

Answer (score 2):

In this paper: [Unsupervised Machine Translation Using Monolingual Corpora Only](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00043)
 the authors proposed a novel method.

[image]

Intuitively it is an autoencoder, but the Start Of Sentence token is set to be the language type.

One other advanced method is to use the pre-training model. In this paper: [Cross-lingual Language Model Pretraining](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.07291.pdf) researchers proposed an algorithm that utilized the pre-trained multi-lingual trained BERT(with labeled data but we don't need to have a labeled dataset for our task) and the autoencoder mentioned previously.

Comment: That's crazy! I wonder if it could be a way of addressing the grounding problem too, if  media experiences could somehow be mapped to a shared embedding space . . .

Comment: @NeilSlater I know only a little about the "grounding problem" but I thought this paper would be helpful to you: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.05518.pdf